# QT 5.11 macdeployqt mingw not installed by default?

Tags: qt, qt5

I do not have the macdeployqt installed on Windows 10 alongside of the windeployqt tool. Nothing relevant or useful appears when searching about this issue so I'm forced to resort to stackoverflow.

windeployqt works fine, however the macdeployqt tool is not there. Is there a way to download the tool from somewhere possibly via the presently non working maintenance tool (due to the default repositories not working for me on QT5.11)?

Comment: Is it even possible to _compile_ a Mac version of a Qt app on Windows?

Comment: You need an OSX machine (in practice, legally, an actual Mac computer) to build an OSX version of your software.

Answer (score 1):

The macdeploy tool's source code is shipped with Qt sources (qt-src\qttools\src\macdeployqt). Most of it's source code is within **#ifdef Q_OS_DARWIN**-blocks, and it's linked against Apple's CoreFoundation Framework, so I don't think you will ever get the macdeploy-tool to work on windows. Im curious how you compiled your application that you're trying to bundle; afaik you cannot cross-compile in a meaningful way as the CoreFoundation and other Mac-Frameworks are not available on any other platform.